# What are the options for a person or business that needs high bandwidth internet service?

Tags: bandwidth, isp

What are the options for a business that needs high bandwidth internet service?

For example, how would a large hotel or medium sized business with a few hundred employees get enough bandwidth to service everyone?

Have looked into this a bunch, but could only find the following options when it comes to high bandwidth internet service:

- Gigabit internet is available to consumers and businesses in very few select markets in the US
- Verizon FIOS offers up to 300mps down, 65mps up in a broader range of select markets
- Cable internet is available in most markets, but seems to typically be limited to 100 down, 10 up

I'm left wondering what do the majority of businesses that need more bandwidth do? Do they just get multiple cable lines? Or are there ISPs that serve businesses that I'm not finding through a normal google search?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you are investing millions of dollars into a hotel then you have the ability to run several dedecated lines for this sort of thing. The first thing I would point out, at that scale, you would be your own provider and would have only paid somebody for the backend.  These options are not advertised because those customers already know those solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is when you call the cable company and make outlandish requests for stuff like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Carrier_transmission_rates

Although you would be surprised at how well a 50 Mb line performs for a hundred+ users if you throttle torrenting and video streaming. Not to mention http proxies for caching etc.

Answer (score 1):

The options you mention are the 'standard' low-end services. If you need more bandwidth, higher availability, redundancy etc. then you usually get one or more leased lines with internet connectivity on them.

Prices for such services aren't standard because they usually involve digging in new fibre optic cables. All the major business ISPs are probably capable of offering you such connections, but you'll probably have to call them to get a quote.